# How to fix GLB/GLTF exporter from exporting a single mesh as several meshes

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

Currently im trying to export a bunch of meshes to three.js, but for some reason. GLB exporter converts my single mesh, into a group of varying sizes.

The reason this sucks is because:

1. Im rendering these in webgl, so each mesh is its own draw call.
2. upon examining the group, theres no reason why its made a certain thing its own mesh. see pictures for example

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to properly export complex meshes as a single mesh and not a group? Im using blender 2.8 to export the models, and they are grouped in blender as a single model

Comment: Does the mesh use multiple materials? If so, that's why glTF export is splitting the mesh – multiple materials will always be multiple draw calls in WebGL. One option would be to use vertex colors and a single material, instead.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy no, everything has  a single material, and single UV map.

Comment: Hm, could you share the `.blend` file? The only other reason I can think of that it would create a Group is if the mesh contains too many vertices for a single indexed draw call.